# How to check Multiple FileType condition in S3 preSignedURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

```
s3.createPresignedPost({
    ...
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Fields: {
      Key: fileName,
    },
    Conditions:[
      ['eq','$Content-Type',"text/csv"]
      ['eq','$Content-Type',"text/xls"]
      ['eq','$Content-Type',"text/xlsx"]
    ],
    Expires:100
    ...
})
```

is it a valid condition to allow uploading csv, xls and xlsx through presignedURL. if not what is the correct way to allow the multiple file types upload through presignedURL

Comment: Believe that conditions are ANDed. I'd investigate the starts-with options for "text/csv,text/xls,text/xlsx".

Comment: `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "text/csv,text/xls,text/xlsx"]` is this what you are saying

Comment: Yes, that is what I was proposing. The documentation is a little unclear.

Comment: So it will allow csv or xls or xlsx type files upload through preSignedURL if any other type files are uploaded it will throw error. am I correct

Comment: `<Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "text/csv,text/xls,text/xlsx"]</Message>` this is the error I got

Comment: Did you try with just `text/csv` or even `text/`? It would be valuable to know if you an get that to work then proceed to the multiple content types.

Comment: but if we use `text/` it will accept all the file types starting with `text`. my use case it should only accept csv or xls and xlsx

Comment: The point is to validate whether or not you can get any content-type validation to work.

Comment: I can't get you, can you explain a bit please

Comment: I am suggesting that you test with a simple policy that has a single `starts-with` condition of text/csv. Generate a pre-signed URL and test POST of an actual CSV file to that URL. Does it work? If it works, that's a good sign. Next upload a non-CSV. Does that fail? If it fails, that's also a good sign, because now we know how to create working pre-signed URLs that restrict uploads to a single content type. If all that works as expected, then you can begin to investigate multiple content types, as suggested earlier.

Comment: I tried with: `[{'Content-Type': 'text/csv'}]`  and got an error `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$Content-Type", "text/csv"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241842/discussion-between-jarmod-and-athavan-t).